# I'm unable to send or receive messages from a Python client to Kafka

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a pod that runs Kafka and ZooKeeper and connect to it via Python. However, with my current configuration, I'm unable to send or receive messages from the Python client, although I can successfully connect to the port exposed by Kafka.
I'm currently experiencing issues with my pod configuration. I've defined topics and checked in Lens which port the Kafka service exposed. I can confirm that it's connecting to Kafka, but when I send messages from a producer and access the container, none of them arrive. Similarly, no information is received from the consumer. I've already ruled out errors related to ports or topics as I've checked them thoroughly.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka-zookeeper
spec:
  serviceName: kafka-zookeeper-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zookeeper
        image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.9
        env:
        - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
          value: "yes"
        - name: ZOO_VOLUME_DIR
          value: /bitnami/zookeeper
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
          name: zookeeper
        volumeMounts:
        - name: zookeeper-data
          mountPath: /bitnami/zookeeper
      - name: kafka
        image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.4
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: kafka-zookeeper-service:2181

        - name: KAFKA_VOLUME_DIR
          value: /bitnami/kafka

        - name: KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
          value: "true"

        - name: KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES
          value: controller,broker

        - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS
          value: "PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093"

        - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
          value: "CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT"

        - name: KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS
          value: "1001@localhost:9093"

        - name: KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES
          value: "CONTROLLER"

        - name: KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID
          value: "1001"

        - name: KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_METADATA_MIGRATION_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
          name: kafka
        - containerPort: 9093
          name: kafka-plaintext
        - containerPort: 9094
          name: kafka-tls
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kafka-data
          mountPath: /bitnami/kafka
      volumes:
      - name: zookeeper-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: zookeeper-data-pvc
      - name: kafka-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: kafka-data-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-data-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kafka-data-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-zookeeper-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka-zookeeper
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 2181
    targetPort: 2181
    name: zookeeper
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9092
    targetPort: 9092
    name: kafka
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9093
    targetPort: 9093
    name: kafka-plaintext
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9094
    targetPort: 9094
    name: kafka-tls
```

> **Producer**

from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json

```
def main():
    bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:34715'
    topic = 'dev'
    message = {'message': 'Hello from the producer'}

    try:
        producer = KafkaProducer(
            bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
            value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')
        )
        print("Successful connection to Kafka server at:", bootstrap_servers)
        producer.send(topic, value=message)
        print("Message sent successfully to topic:", topic)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending message:", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> **Consumer**

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

def main():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('dev', bootstrap_servers='localhost:34715')

    try:
        for message in consumer:
            print(f'Message received: {message.value.decode("utf-8")}')
    finally:
        consumer.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the messaging system?  What does that code look like, where is it running, how is it configured, and what specific error do you get?

Comment: I've already updated the code and added the Python code for the consumer and producer

Comment: Where is this code running?  Where is the hard-coded `localhost:34715` address supposed to connect to?  In a Kubernetes context, I might normally expect these processes to run in their own separate Deployments, and to use the Service name and the standard Kafka port; `kafka-zookeeper-service:9292`.

Comment: (I also might split ZooKeeper and Kafka into their own separate StatefulSets, and use `volumeClaimTemplates:` in those StatefulSets over manually declaring your own PersistentVolumeClaims.  That's probably secondary to your issue though.)

Comment: How do I connect to the pod via a remote service with the port perfectly randomized, it could be any value, In this case, if it were incorrect, it would throw an error, but if it behaves as it should, it will.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `flush` to ensure the message is sent immediately and `close` function?

```
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer

def main():
    bootstrap_servers = 'localhost:34715'
    topic = 'dev'
    message = {'message': 'Hello from the producer'}

    try:
        producer = KafkaProducer(
            bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
            value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')
        )
        print("Successful connection to Kafka server at:", bootstrap_servers)
        producer.send(topic, value=message)
        print("Message sent successfully to topic:", topic)
        # Flush the producer to ensure the message is sent
        producer.flush()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending message:", e)
    finally:
        # Close the producer
        producer.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I made the modification, ran the code, but I'm still not receiving any messages.

Comment: Did you check that topic exist? Also did you run port-forward command with correct ports?

Comment: I have no name!@kafka-zookeeper-0:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin$ kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
__consumer_offsets
dev